# Syntax error in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a syntax challenge that is returning a "Data Mismatch" error

Basically, I am using the VBA `DMin` function to target a range of prices using two criteria, one string and one date.

The code:

```
EndDate = #11/1/2017#

Target = DMin("Price", "qryPrice", " [CodeName]='Macan'" And " [MyDate] <=" & EndDate)
```

I can't seem to figure out the syntax in order to use both of the different criteria data types. `[CodeName]` is string, `[MyDate]` is date/time

Comment: Try maybe EndDate = #11/01/2017#? From here I can't tell if this is DD/MM/YYYY, or MM/DD/YYYY. Maybe try a different date where the day is bigger than 12?

Comment: Thank you for you response. I will attempt your suggestion and hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quote marks around `And`. Try # delimiters.

`Target = DMin("Price", "qryPrice", "[CodeName]='Macan' And [MyDate] <=#" & EndDate & "#")`

Why hard-coded date? Could just put the date directly in the DMin() expression.

Shouldn't CodeName and EndDate be dynamic?

Comment: Thanks for your response. CodeName is hard-coded because I am testing for a unique case. Only one of these CodeNames is relevant for my purposes, it being Macan. 

I've tried putting the date directly in the Dmin() function, but if I remember correctly the error then notified me that I need an Object, or that the Object was not defined. This is a table that I want filtered by CodeName and Date, so I was unsure what the Object would be.

Answer (score 0):

You should always format your date values to string expressions when concatenating:

```
Target = DMin("Price", "qryPrice", "[CodeName]='" & [SomeCodeName] & "' And [MyDate] <= #" & Format([EndDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```